# SWT Label Drag'n'Drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, label, eclipse-rcp

I'm surprised to see that this hasn't been done, or at least my research says so.

I have a `Canvas` with `RowLayout` and a bunch of `Label`s.

The title is pretty straight forward: I want to reorder my labels using DND.

Please don't tell me I have to engineer my own algorithm for calculating bounds and sizes and stuff like that.

**Later edit:**

I'm considering using `Zest`, but again, I can't find any example where graph nodes are snapped to eachother.

Comment: Did you consider using something like [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/)?

Comment: Yes, I have. I want that to be my last resort, because I don't want to overengineer my widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this about a year ago.

My method of solving this problem was to use a data model to hold the label information.  Use the canvas.getChildren() and search for a separator composite between each object or the label that you dropped on top of.  When a drag and drop operation was completed you would search for the item that you dropped on and move the reference to the appropriate position in the model. Then reset the information on each label.  Only requirement to do this is to keep a data structure with the label info and a reference to the canvas.

Comment: I've thought of this myself, but how do I know which control is under my mouse when I execute the drop? Just iterate through the children and check their bounds?

Comment: Something like the following:

public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    Object src = dtde.getSource();
    List<Control> children = canvas.getChildren();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
        if (children.get(i).equals(src)) {
            //update
        }
    }
}

Comment: Additionally, if the contents of the labels are unique, you could look at the contents of the label you dropped on and cycle through the model to determine the position that you dropped at.  You would just have to caste the object returned to a control that lets you get access to the text contained in the control; so, at a minimum, caste to composite or label. The method to do this is somewhat similar in that your perform String targetKey = ((Composite/Label)dtde.getSource()).getText();  Then just search the model for the index to insert the transfer source and update as needed.

Comment: I want to implement the widget with `Presentation Objects`: POJOs that hold information on the label and its container. I think my drag data will hold the PO, because it would make my life easier in the `drop event` method (I'll have access to both label and PO).

Comment: You helped me figure out the implementation for what I'm needing. Thank you, thumbs up.

Comment: Did a blog post on this, with source code. http://georgiangrec.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/swt-composite-drag-and-drop/